# Failed to emerge dev-libs/boost-1.63.0 (incompatible properties)

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I am trying to install gentoo (genkernel) and I have boost as dependency. I got this error in log file:
What is the problem?

> ```
>  b2
>  --user-config=/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/work/boost_1_63_0-abi_x86_64.amd64/user-config.jam
>  gentoodebug -j2 -q -d+2 -sICU_PATH=/usr pch=off
>  --boost-build=/usr/share/boost-build --prefix=/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/image/usr --layout=system threading=multi link=shared,static Performing configuration checks
>
> - 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
> - 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
> - arm                      : no  (cached)
> - mips1                    : no  (cached)
> - power                    : no  (cached)
> - sparc                    : no  (cached)
> - x86                      : yes (cached)
> - symlinks supported       : yes
> - has_icu builds           : yes (cached)
> - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes (cached)
> error: Name clash for '<p../dist/bin>auto_index'
> error:  
> error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
> error: these incompatible properties:
> error:
> error:     -  none
> error:     -  <format>html
> error:
> error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for
> these  error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for
> install error: targets.
>
> ERROR: dev-libs/boost-1.63.0::gentoo failed (compile phase):       
> Building of Boost tools failed
> Call stack:  
>      ebuild.sh, line  124: Called src_compile
> environment, line 4352:  Called multilib-minimal_src_compile  
> environment, line 2469:  Called multilib_foreach_abi 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile' 
> environment, line 2700:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
> environment, line 2347:  Called _multibuild_run _multilib_multibuild_wrapper' 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
> environment, line 2345:  Called _multilib_multibuild_wrapper 'multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile'
> environment, line 413:  Called multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile
> environment, line 2463:  Called multilib_src_compile  
> environment, line 2960:  Called die
> The specific snippet of code:
> ejam "${OPTIONS[@]}" ${PYTHON_OPTIONS} || die "Building of Boost tools failed"; 
> If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-libs/boost-1.63.0::gentoo'`,
> the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-libs/boost-1.63.0::gentoo'`.
> The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/temp/build.log'. 
> The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/temp/environment'. 
> Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/work/boost_1_63_0-abi_x86_64.amd64/tools'
> S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/boost-1.63.0/work/boost_1_63_0'
> ```

Comment: `euse -D tools -p dev-libs/boost` (https://bugs.gentoo.org/585336#c3)